# Is the "api" tag a too broad one, and a candidate for burninating?

Tags: support, tags

There are more than 45,000 questions using [api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/api). Those questions have very little in common, except that they are related to an API, in some way.

Isn't [api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/api) too broad? If it is too broad, should not it be burninated?

To me, it seems a meta tag, as it cannot be used alone, and it has a different meaning to different people. For example, if you ask about an API to Drupal developers, they will think of Drupal API; if you ask about the API to Windows developers, they will think of something different (even if it is still an API).

Comment: It could (in theory) relate to questions about developing an API of your own.

Comment: @AnnaLear: under such a circumstance, wouldn't (for example) `api-dev` (or a more 'full' `api-development`) be appropriate? Otherwise it does seem to be more a meta-tag than a useful question-type identifier.

Comment: @DavidThomas I've favour [api-development] myself.

Comment: @AnnaLear: Me too, in all honesty. =)

Comment: [tag:api-design] already exists

Comment: In this day and age I actually agree with this statement. Talk to webservice designers and you have a whole new landscape of APIs and API design.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I disagree with your judgement that it's a meta tag:

- The tag would typically be used in combination with a programming language tag, but that always goes on SO. Conceivably, a question about API design could be tagged just [api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/api).
- The tag's meaning is not ambiguous. Of course drupalers will think of the Drupal API and so on. Similarly, if you tell me about C, I think about embedded or unix programming, but it's still the same language if you're using it on Windows.

In principle, a tag like this should be cleaned up, not removed. However, this tag is very heavily abused to mean “I'm using some API”. This usage is completely meaningless: every program uses an API (even if you're programming on bare metal, you're using a hardware API). So I'm not convinced that cleaning up the tag to remove it from 90% of the questions that have it, and subsequently fighting off new misuse, is worth the trouble.

I think the best course of action would be to pick a new tag name ([api-design](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/api-design) already exists), scour [api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/api) for questions to retag, and after a while burninate the tag.

Comment: There are **17,000** questions in the tag now.  How can we effectively separate the wheat from the chaff?  What tag combos should we look for?

Comment: Nearly 42K now, and nothing seems to have improved...

Comment: I think a question about API design would better be tagged api-design

Comment: 59K+ Now, with just a better excerpt!

Comment: It is still increasing flat 92,000 questions currently