# Isn't [api] a meta-tag that should be removed?

Tags: discussion, tags, burninate-request

Questions on Stack Overflow are about programming and a lot of programming questions are related to any kind of *Application Programming Interface*, but the tag [api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/api) is never useful as a tag for question. Instead tags for the specific API should be used or what kind of API it is about.

The blog post [The death of meta tags](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/08/07/the-death-of-meta-tags/) proclaims meta tags are a problem and describes how to tell a meta tag from a tag

> How can you tell you’re using a meta-tag? It’s easier than you might think.
>
> - If the tag can’t work as the only tag on a question, it’s probably a meta-tag. Every tag you use should be able to work, more or less, as the only tag on a question.
> - Meta-tags are actually a subset of a larger problem that I usually call dependent tags. These are tags that don’t say anything by themselves – you can’t tell what the question is about unless they’re paired with some other tag

The tag excerpt even begins with:

> DO NOT USE THIS TAG ALONE. Tagging with the library like [api-design] or a specific tag like [google-api] is preferred, where applicable.

A previous [answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/272014/213269) put it like this:

> However, this tag is very heavily abused to mean “I'm using some API”. This usage is completely meaningless: every program uses an API (even if you're programming on bare metal, you're using a hardware API).

I agree that this usage does not add anything. Whit that context, I don't think there should be a big problem to remove the tag.

In my point of view, the [api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/api) is not useful to describe the content in questions, perhaps its better to remove it?

Comment: FWIW it's not that feasible to request burnination of a tag with so many questions (nearly 100k), especially now that Shog is no longer at the company to facilitate them.